# HIKARICP Killing Connections

Tags: spring, hikaricp

Can someone help me understand the Hikari implementation better. We currently have the following settings in use:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=3
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=1
```

What we see, is that after 10 min, the applications connections are cleared, and then, it struggles to make new connections to the DB, resulting in sessions exceeded errors, from the DB, we understand what they are, but it seems that rather than use the existing sessions, Hikari is trying to create new sessions, and the DB is not allowing that as is it supposed to.

Why is Hikari trying to establish new connections and not use connections from the available sessions ont he DB?

How does the maxlifetime work? reading the documents on the Hikari Git hub page, it seems straightforward enough.

We have also set

```
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
```

on the idea that it may not kill those connections quite so quickly, but it still seems to remove them...

Thanks

Comment: Hikari only delegates to the underlying driver. When the connections are closed (after 10 minutes as you configured it), it will reopen connections. Depending not he driver it might or might not reuse sessions. I wonder why aren't the sessions closed/cleaned on the server when the connection is closed (as they should imho) as the active connections are gone as well.

Comment: Hey, yeah that is what I thought should happen..I will ask the question around that